# Web API not working. Trying a simple Reverse String function

Tags: c#, .net

I was trying to test my web API on postman but it isn't working I checked all 3 of my files and functions it shows no errors. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong. Im learning how to make new Web APIs for an internship my mentor asked me to do this. Thank you for anyone helping me
Here is my WebApiConfig.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my ReverseStringController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace ReverseStringAPI.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/[controller]")]
    public class ReverseStringController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult ReverseString([FromBody] string input)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            {
                return BadRequest("Input string is required.");
            }

            char[] charArray = input.ToCharArray();

            Array.Reverse(charArray);

            string reversedString = new string(charArray);

            return Ok(reversedString);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Global.asax.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }

    }
}
```

I tried rerouting to fix did not work.

This is the error on Postman

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The resource cannot be found.</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:pointer; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>The resource cannot be found.</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. &nbsp;Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
            <br><br>

            <b> Requested URL: </b>/api/ReverseString<br><br>

            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

            <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4494.0

            </font>

    </body>
</html>
<!-- 
[HttpException]: The controller for path &#39;/api/ReverseString&#39; was not found or does not implement IController.
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
-->
```

Comment: Can you share the info on how you send the request to mentioned API action? Please specify what's not working.

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: I posted the error on postman

Comment: `Im learning how to make new Web APIs for an internship my mentor asked me to do this` you're learning old ASP.NET web API. Learn ASP.NET Core instead.

Answer (score 1):

The URL you're requesting is this:

```
/api/ReverseString
```

Let's take a look at [how Web API uses routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api), specifically:

> - To find the controller, Web API adds "Controller" to the value of the {controller} variable.
> - To find the action, **Web API looks at the HTTP verb, and then looks for an action whose name begins with that HTTP verb name.** For example, with a GET request, Web API looks for an action prefixed with "Get", such as "GetContact" or "GetAllContacts". This convention applies only to GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS, and PATCH verbs. You can enable other HTTP verbs by using attributes on your controller. We'll see an example of that later.

So the framework is able to find your `ReverseStringController`, but there's nothing telling it what *method* to find on that controller.

Rename the method to something matching the HTTP verb being used, such as `PostReverseString`.

---

Alternatively, you can add a route attribute to the method to explicitly indicate the route.  The controller already has a route prefix:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/[controller]")]
```

And the URL you're using matches exactly that, so you can use an empty route attribute value on the method:

```
[Route("")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult ReverseString([FromBody] string input)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have marked your ReverseString method with HttpPost attribute. Check whether you are really using POST method in Postman when calling it. Also the method's parameter you need to specify in request's body (as opposed to specifying it in url).

[image]